# Deleting a HTML table row on successful ajax request

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

This below code i am using to create a dynamic table on search results. its basically a jquery code which takes the search results from the backend and creates a table

```js
$('#search-movie').on('submit',function (e) {
                 $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/search',
                  data: $('#search-movie').serialize(),
                   success: function (q) {
                   
                    var trHTML='';
                    $.each(q, function (i, userData) {
                                for(j=0; j<userData.length; j++)
                                {
                           
                                trHTML +=
                                        '<tr><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].showid
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].typeof
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].title
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].directors
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].cast
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].country
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].releaseyear
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].rating
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].duration
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].listedin
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + userData[j].description
                                        // + '</td></tr style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + '</td><td style="padding-right: 10px">'
                                        + '<button type="button" id="button2" class="btnSelect" onClick="clickme()">delete</button>'
                                        + '</td></tr>'
                                }
                        });
                        $('#table1').append(trHTML);
                   
                   }
                  });
                 e.preventDefault();
                 });
            
            })
            </script>
```

I am working on deleting a table row on successful ajax response from backend api. I have tried it but its not deleting the table row in the frontend on success ajax response.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#table1").on('click', '.btnSelect', function() {

    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var showid = col1

    $.ajax({
      url: '/delete_movie',
      type: 'POST',
      data: showid,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response[1]);
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Try changing `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` to `currentRow.remove()` - you've already stored the row you want to remove in a variable and `this` *may* change in the ajax success: callback (not sure OTTOMH, not checked)

Comment: Off topic: you probably want to remove `id="button2"` and `onClick="clickme()"` as IDs must be unique and this would give the same id on every row - and you're using class anyway.  `onclick=` will clash with your jquery event handler - use one or the other (protip: use js/jquery event handlers)

Comment: i tired various methods...but ended up with the method which i am currently doing now

Comment: but using my current method...it is able to extract a column value and send that value to the backend which is working fine...but after a success response the deleting the row in the front end where i am stuck now

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o563twzg/1/) that shows your code (more or less) with `currentRow.remove()` working.

Comment: This question [how to access this in ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function)  should answer your question, but you've stated in comments below that it didn't work.

Comment: @freedomn-m, my issue is fixed by doing currentRow.remove(); which was not working previously...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` cascades upwards in the DOM, including itself, so will not find the `<tr>`. You could use `.find()` instead https://api.jquery.com/find/

Instead of using `this`, could you target a specific row class or id?

```
$("#table1 tr.the-row-class").remove();
```

or

```
$("#theRowId").remove();
```

Comment: The row are dynamically generated as per search results... so there is no such rowid or row classes....

Comment: `$(this).find("tr").remove()` might be the best thing then

Comment: The event is `$("#table1").on('click','.btnSelect'` - so `this` is the `btnSelect`, *not* the #table1.

Comment: @MikeIrving, I tired $(this).find("tr").remove() which is not working

Comment: ah ok, I was confused by the id containing `table`. so is the button a nested child of the `<tr>`?

can you post some HTML?

Comment: @freedomn-m how to do this ?

Comment: Try changing `$(this).closest("tr").remove();` to `currentRow.remove()`

Comment: @MikeIrving, so do you need the code where i am generating the tables dynamically?

Comment: @freedomn-m, I tried this currentRow.remove() which is not working

Comment: Can you confirm you get the `alert()` in your success callback

Comment: @MikeIrving, I have edited my question and pasted the dynamic table creation code based on search results

Comment: @freedomn-m, I am getting alert message of the backend response value

Comment: what happens if you change the `on` line to 

    `$("#table1 .btnSelect").click(function(){
        ....
    }` @SagabarnisaS?

Comment: I hope you are asking about functionality...? it is checking the current row of the button click and taking the first column and sending to the backend

Comment: @MikeIrving `$("#table1 .btnSelect").length == 0` when the code runs as the buttons are added to the table dynamically, so that would not work.  OP is using the correct event delegation, that's not the problem.  The problem is the use of `this` inside the success: callback.

Comment: @SagabarnisaS if you do a `console.log(this)` in the callback, what does it think `this` is?

Comment: I also thought the same...but i tried using currentRow.remove(); to remove the row...but it is also not working

Comment: @MikeIrving `this` is the ajax settings (by default): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22629978/2181514

Comment: currentRow.remove(); is working now....i dont know whats the magic

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){

               
                $("#table1").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
                    
                    var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
                    
                    var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
                    
                    var showid=col1
                    
                    $.ajax({ 
                            url: '/delete_movie', 
                            type: 'POST', 
                            data: showid,
                            success: function(response){ 
                               alert(response[1]);
                               console.log(this);
                               currentRow.remove(); //changing this line fixes the issue
                            } 
                        })
                });
                });
            </script>
```